# Need help in SSRS text box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, powerbi-paginated-reports

In my SSRS report, I have a country column. I grouped the country column and added the page break between each instance, and I added the country name in the text box and  added the country field in the expression(FIrst(=Fields!Country.Value), but I am getting all the pages with the same country name only.I need the output each page different country name in the text box

I need country name based upon the page break

Comment: Share you report design other wise it's impossible to tell you exactly what is wrong. However, I would *guess* that you have put the textbox outside the country row group. If it's outside the group, it has no context so therefore `FIRST()` means first in the dataset rather than first in the group.

Comment: Yes I put my text box outside group, how i can add the text box in the row group

Comment: Edit your question and show your report design.